# How to create common/shared instance in vba

Tags: vba

I would like to create one instance of class that all other
could use so far I create each instance in each class that needes its methods.

Is there a way that I could create only one instance which would be seen by other classes.

Normaly I could create some sort of static variable that would be seen by others. 
But it seems not possible in VBA :/

Answer (score 17):

In a Module:

```
Private objSharedClass As myClass

Public Function GetShared() As myClass

    If objSharedClass Is Nothing Then
        Set objSharedClass = New myClass
    End If

    Set GetShared = objSharedClass

End Function
```

It's the VB(A) implementation of the Singleton pattern. You need to consider carefully whether or not it's really appropriate, and if so, that's the way to do it. When I use it, I usually put the above code in a Module by itself (except that if I'm using more than one Singleton in the application I put them all together in a single Module). You can add a destruction routine to the same module and call it from your application exit:

```
Public Sub CloseSingleton()

    Set objSharedClass = Nothing

End Sub
```

Or you can just let it go out of scope when the app closes--not as tidy, but I've never seen it cause a problem (I usually do clean up, though...).

**EDIT**

Usage (just in case it's not obvious). Either:

```
...
Set objLocalCopy = GetShared
DoSomethingWith objLocalCopy.MethodOrProperty
...
```

Or:

```
...
DoSomethingWith GetShared.MethodOrProperty
...
```

The first is preferable if you're going to use the shared class more than once in the calling routine, but the second works fine for a single call.

Answer (score 4):

Make the sub or function in a Module and you'll be able to access it from your other classes.

```
ModuleName.MethodName
```

Comment: ++ and yeah it's that simple :)