# Private Sub App_SheetChange Doesnt work if an error occurs in a previous macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to activate a macro when a change is made to cell A1

**Class Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Sh.Name = "S" Then

    Dim rngKeyCells As Range
    Set rngKeyCells = Sh.Range("A1")

    If Intersect(rngKeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.Run "a"

    End If

End Sub
```

**This_Workbook Code**

```
Private OurEventHandler As EventHandler

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Initiates the data change when the filter is changed
    Set OurEventHandler = New EventHandler

End Sub
```

This works absolutely fine usually, however an issue occurs if i try making a change in A1 after i open VBA.

It will work fine 90% of the time but if during one of the previous macro's that i run, there is an error, it won't work.

Example - I run a macro that deletes the Worksheet to the left of the active one. If there is no worksheet to the left of the active one it will error. I press end and that's fine. Now if i try to change the cells A1 and expect the macro above to run, nothing happens.

Is this the kind of thing that is solvable without showing the entire macro? Or could it be something that is inbuilt into the rest of the macro that is causing the issue?

Thanks

Comment: If an error occurs, VBA will be "reset". This means that all stored variables like `App` will not be set anymore. You need to change your code to "avoid" the error or use an error handler for that point... also `On Error Resume next` prior to the code can help (in a dirty way)

Comment: Ah i see, makes sense. There are quite a few ways of creating a error so I don't think it will be efficient to make the code "avoid" all of these errors. Might just be something i have to live with

Comment: To me it sounds like you have to check if there is a worksheet `to the left` before you try to remove it. This way rather than ignoring the error you can handle the actual issue

Answer (score 0):

In the programming there is something named **Design Patterns**. In your case, it would be really useful to make a **Singleton** for the `App` variable.

Here is a good example of it for VBA:
[How to create common/shared instance in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329428/how-to-create-common-shared-instance-in-vba?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments: When an error happens and `end` is pressed, the whole VBA-Context is reset, the content of global Vars is lost (so your variable `OurEventHandler` is `nothing`).

If you can't catch all errors to ensure that this reset isn't happening (and I think you never really can), maybe it is easiest to implement the event handler in the worksheet itself:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Ne need to check Worksheet as the Hander is valid only for the Worksheet
    if target.row = 1 and target.column = 1 then
        Application.Run "AIMS_and_eFEAS_Report.AIMS_Criteria"
    end if
End Sub
```