# Circular Dependency Error when using Enumerations

Tags: vba

I want to assign certain time weightage values to the variables of a data set. So I am trying to use Enumerations/Constants so to improve my code quality and make it easy to maintain. But on compiling my project, it throws in a  [Circular Dependencies Between Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/circular-dependencies-between-modules#:%7E:text=Circular%20references%20between%20modules%2C%20constants,defined%20types%20aren%27t%20allowed.&text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20type%20or,Remove%20the%20dependent%20references.) error.

What I have understood is, one is allowed to use only constants [Eg: 2,3.14,56....], in the truest sense of the word. Bottom line, if I can't use Either Enumerations or Constants. Then how can I achieve my objective of keeping my weightages code-block, in a way that any changes in them is reflected everywhere in my project than me having to do a find and update manually every instance.

*What I am getting at, is to have a global variable that can be accessed throughout the project and is dynamic.*

```
Private Const Wtage As Double = ConvTohr(34) 'Error happens here

Enum Weightage
   Var1_Weightage = ConvTohr(3)  'Error happens here
   Var2_Weightage = ConvTohr(11)
   Var3_Weightage = ConvTohr(2)
   var4_Weightage = ConvTohr(9)
   var5_Weightage = ConvTohr(0)
End Enum

Private Function ConvTohr(val As Integer) As Double
    If val = 0 Then
       ConvTohr = 0
       Exit Function
    End If
    ConvTohr = Round((val / 60), 2)
End Function
```

[image: Error Snap]

Comment: `Const` values in VBA must be literals or an expression involving only other named `Consts`. You cannot assign a function result to a `Const` field in VBA.

Comment: Also, your `ConvTohr` function returns `Double` but your `Wtage` is `Integer` - you need to fix that first.

Comment: Also, you should read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/const-statement - and note the restrictions on the _`expression`_ part of the syntax.

Comment: Also, VBA's `Enum` type can only use `Integer` or `Long` values for its members, you cannot use `Double` values for `Enum` members (as your `ConvTohr` function returns `Double`).

Comment: Okay. Points noted. Thanks. So is there any other way I can replicate the functionality of Enums without these restrictions ? What I am getting at is to have a global variable that can be accessed throughout the project and is dynamic ?

Comment: Use a singleton `Class Module` with `Get`-properties to expose those values (VBA doesn't support true singletons, but it can be worked-around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4338092/159145 ).

Comment: I'm wrong about using `Class Module`, all you need is a `Module`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The error message is incorrect: *your code does not have any circular references*.

  - This is more of a bug in the VBA interpreter: your code is still incorrect and invalid, but VBA is showing the wrong error message.
  - Given that VBA remains effectively frozen-in-time since 2002 (excepting 64-bit support in 2007), so don't expect any fixes, let alone any enhancements, *ever* (Though MS Office's COM automation tooling is *slowly* shifting to JavaScript (maybe Python? *please?*).
- The actual problem with your code is threefold:

  - You cannot use a `Function` to initialize a `Const` value in VBA.
  - You cannot use a `Function` to define values for a VBA `Enum` either.
  - You cannot have `Enum` members typed as `Double`: VBA only supports `Integer` and `Long` values for `Enum` members.

    - Curiously, VBA *does* allow `Const` values to be typed as `Double` - but most other languages don't because `Double` is an IEEE-754 floating point type that does not have a machine-portable representation, but as VBA is *only* for Win32 on x86/x64 I guess that means Microsoft made it work given the very narrow gamut of hardware that VBA programs will run on.

---

Anyway, if you want "named values" typed as `Double` that you can use anywhere, then try this:

1. Create a new `Module` (not a `Class Module`).
2. Rename the Module from `Module1` to `Weightage`.
3. Put this code in `Weightage`:

   ```
   Private Function ConvTohr(val As Integer) As Double
       ConvTohr = Round((val / 60), 2)
   End Function

   Public Property Get Var1_Weightage() As Double
       Var1_Weightage = ConvTohr(3)
   End Property
   Public Property Get Var2_Weightage() As Double
       Var2_Weightage = ConvTohr(11)
   End Property
   Public Property Get Var3_Weightage() As Double
       Var3_Weightage = ConvTohr(2)
   End Property
   Public Property Get Var4_Weightage() As Double
       Var4_Weightage = ConvTohr(9)
   End Property
   Public Property Get Var5_Weightage() As Double
       Var5_Weightage = ConvTohr(0)
   End Property
   ```
4. Screenshot proof:

   (See output in the Immediate pane):

   [image]

Comment: Neato. Thanks much for a solution and the accompanying notes... :)